# How to edit a pixel without modifying surrounding pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, pixel, image-editing, cs4

When working on a bitmap image in Photoshop, I often need to make changes to  individual pixels, such as using the Paintbrush to change the colour. This would typically involve zooming into the maximum level possible - 3200% - then using a 1px brush to paint the individual pixels, as seen below. However, this has the unwanted effect of also changing the colour of the surrounding pixels to a lesser degree.

[image]

How can I avoid this behaviour to modify the properties of only a single pixel? I've come across the workaround of creating a 1px x 1px fixed size selection around the pixel as I'm working on it, thereby preventing the surrounding pixels from being affected, but this seems like a convoluted, time-consuming hack more than a real solution. Is there nothing in Photoshop designed for this purpose - or at the very least, a hack or plugin that would be less time-consuming?

Comment: You don't have a true bitmap image there. A bitmap image won't have any gray pixels. It looks like the anti-aliasing of a grayscale image is what's throwing you off.

Comment: @GoofyMonkey: what are you talking about?

Comment: @GoofyMonkey A bitmap/raster image is simply an image composed of pixels, as opposed to a vector image, which is composed of mathematical lines and curves. Colour has absolutely no correlation as to whether an image is a bitmap or not, at least not as far as I know.

Comment: I have already forgotten most of Photoshop features since I haven't used it for long time, but I think there's a "hardness" parameter for Brush tool?

Comment: @Hashim - That is actually incorrect. Bit means Binary Integer (0/1) - if you have a map of binary integers you have a two value image. That is what a bitmap is,  a two value array where each value is either "high" or "low". People do incorrectly referer to pixmaps as bitmaps but a bitmap is always specifically two colors as each bit can only be "high" or "low". i.e. "In computer graphics, when the domain is a rectangle (indexed by two coordinates) a bitmap gives a way to store a binary image, that is, an image in which each pixel is either black or white (or any two colors)." - wikipedia

Comment: The Wikipedia article indicates 'bitmap' is commonly used to refer to pixmaps. In 25 years of using computers, this is the first time I've come across the pixmap/bitmap distinction. Pretty much everybody uses "bitmap" when they want to specify that an image is composed of pixels rather than vectors.

Comment: @Hobbs I've had to use True Bitmapped images for some types of barcodes for medical packaging. Though not common a real Bitmap image is made up of only black or white (on or off) pixels. There is no gray. While it is common to refer to pixelated or raster images as bitmap it's not correct. Try converting an image or shape in Photoshop to the Bitmap colour mode. You'll see what I was referring to.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll want to use the Pencil tool instead of Brush tool. It allows you to do pixel level edits without any anti-aliasing (the fuzzy area). It's located below the Brush tool or can be accessed by repeatedly pressing<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> until it cycles around.

Comment: Thank you, that does the job perfectly. Is there any particular technical reason that the results from the brush are inherently anti-aliased? Could Adobe not have made this possible with the brush too? Do competing products work in the same way?

Comment: @Hashim There is no technical reason brush couldn't be the pen tool (then people using brush would use another tool for brushing and your question would be is there a reason why X isnt Y etc). But then the brush tool would be bad for brushwork as it couldn't account for sub pixel accuracy. So you in fact need both for different reasons.

Comment: @Hashim Subpixel brushes are great for photomanipulation.